# Modifying ObservableCollection while it is being displayed

Tags: wpf, treeview, observablecollection

I have a tree view in which the ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection. I am dynamically loading the children contents every time the user expands the subtree by using a background worker and modifying the underlying ObservableCollection that corresponds to the children nodes. However, when I try to modify this ObservableCollection inside that thread, it will fail IF AND ONLY IF the tree is already expanded (meaning that if the number of children is small, then it will correctly populate).

What I am hoping to achieve is once I expand the tree, I can see children being dynamically populated as they get processed. How can I achieve that behavior using ObservableCollection?

Comment: How does it fail? Are you invoking the `RunWorkerAsync()` method?

Comment: It silently fails. I am running debugging on VS, and when debugger hits collection.clear() inside Background worker thread, it just exits. When I tried to evaluate that expression, I get "NotSupportedException"

Comment: Yes I am invoking RunWorkerAsync to start my background thread.

Comment: Weird part is that it only fails if the number of children is too big (presumably takes too long and the tree already expanded)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I achieve that behavior using ObservableCollection?

The problem is that you aren't allowed to update a collection on a background thread in WPF.  The binding system will automatically marshal most simple bindings to the UI thread, but not collections.  You have two options.

- You can marshal the call to add the data back onto the UI thread using `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.  This will allow the data to be added, but not cause a cross thread exception when WPF updates the binding.
- (If you're using .NET 4.5) You can use the new [EnableCollectionSynchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh140164) on the binding to allow cross-thread access to the collection.

Comment: If I am calling this from a static utility class, how can I access the Dispatcher? Thanks!

Comment: Just kidding, I got it. Application.Current.Dispatcher

Comment: @Reed Copsey, is there an advantage to using one over the other?  I'm new in the WPF world, so my initial approach was to use the BeginInvoke mechanism.  But the second approach seems much simpler.  I'm using .NET 4.5.  Any reason to prefer the former over the latter?